# how to add three button bar item to xib file

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, xib, uibuttonbaritem

I want to add three `buttonbarItem` in my `navigationbarItem` in xib file.
I don't want add these buttons with code (programmatically). I want add these buttons with outlet & action (on xib file) but I can't!!!

I can only add two button right & left side and I can't add last button to navigationbar why???

please guide me how to add three button to xib file navigation...

I create my app with MVC and I want my xib files to be View and I don't want .m or .h file to be View....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is that possible or not , but i have another solution just replace t the UIView to navigation bar and yu can add n number of button's.Simple..........